# How can I remove the Microsoft Virtual PC 2007 splash screen?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, microsoft-virtual-pc, splash

I have an application running on MS-DOS 6.22, which is installed in Microsoft Virtual PC 2007 on a WinVista machine. I would like to eliminate the Virtual PC splash screen that appears when the users boot up the DOS virtual hard disk. I have made as many other changes possible so that the users don't notice that their app is running on a VPC or DOS 6.22.

EDIT: If the VPC2007 spash screen cannot be prevented from displaying, can I replace it with another splash screen of my choice?

Comment: Does [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2007/03/06/setting-up-a-virtual-pc-dos-application.aspx) help? If it does, I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: I already did all of that, thanks anyway!.. I asked this same splash question on Guy's blog but never got a response. What I really would like to do is replace the default VPC2007 splash screen with one of my own choosing. Could I tweak the registry to replace the image, or is it hard-coded into VPC2007?.. I searched in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Virtual PC folder, but could not locate their image file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can remove it ..

download  http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/reshack_setup.exe

Install it then goto C:\Program Files\Microsoft Virtual PC\
right click "Virtual PC.exe" and click open using resource hacker
scroll down to bitmap 250 hit the + sign and click 1033, right click this
delete resource [Bitmap : 250 : 1033], now go to file and save. 
It will auto backup the original as "Virtual PC_original.exe"
there you go no splash!

Comment: Clever and easy-to-use product!