# How can I locate where this splash screen is stored on my computer?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, images, microsoft-virtual-pc, splash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I remove the Microsoft Virtual PC 2007 splash screen?](https://superuser.com/questions/452127/how-can-i-remove-the-microsoft-virtual-pc-2007-splash-screen)

This is the splash screen that appears when I fire up Microsoft Virtual PC 2007 on my WinVista computer. I don't know the file name, image format or the location for this splash screen. How can I find out where its stored?.. I searched in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Virtual PC folder and sub-folders, also searched my entire C: drive, using several educated guesses like VPC, JPG, BMP, PNG, etc. but could not find it!

I would like to supress this splash screen from displaying, so that the application I have running on it appears transparent to the user. I tried using SplashKill, but that didn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Most likely it's embedded within the Virtual PC's executable (.exe) file.

Comment: I looked at vpc.exe with the HxD hex editor, but could not find any file paths for any images in the exe. If this image is embedded within vpc.exe, what would its header info look like in hex format?

Comment: @FrankComputer At this point, you should really consider if it's even *legal* for you to remove the splash screen.  This isn't VirtualBox we're talking about, it's a Microsoft product - they tend not to like when people distribute modified copies of their products.

Comment: Suppressing the splash screen wouldn't make it totally anonymous because the credentials remain the same, there are other references of it displayed elsewhere and this product is free. Microsoft has bigger worries like bootleg copies of Windows, Office, etc.